# How to connect PgAdmin to a PostgreSQL database on cPANEL?

Tags: postgresql, cpanel, pgadmin-4

I'm just trying to access a PostgreSQL database I created on cPANEL via desktop pgAdmin. I have a Server, Host address, Port, and Username/password.

Below you can see the array of information I need to input. In particular I am confused about 'Maintenance database', 'Role', and 'Service.' Under the general tab there is also 'Name', which perhaps I get to choose. Role sounds like it could be to do with permissions but I don't know on what system these are set.
[image]

When attempting to input only the fields I understand, I get 'Unable to connect to server: connection to server *****, port **** failed.. connection refused.' But I'm not sure where this is caused by missing/incorrect information or something to do with networking, ports, firewalls, etc. as this is a subject I don't understand very well.

If it proves impossible to connect via desktop, I could use the built-in phpPgAdmin in cPANEL. I have resisted this so far because I can't see any way to upload a csv to create a table and have had trouble finding clear documentation. But if anyone knows how to do this then it might be easier; either solution would be fine.

Would you be able to offer any pointers on where I might start in troubleshooting either problem?

Comment: Your database is not running on cPanel, because cPanel is an interface to manage a (remote?) host. (see: [cPanel provides the most reliable and intuitive server and site management platform](https://cpanel.net/#:~:text=cPanel%20provides%20the%20most%20reliable%20and%20intuitive%20server%20and%20site%20management%20platform)).  Also [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) is a client to connect to a PostgreSQL database, but it cannot connect to a remote database (unless.... too long to explain here!)

Comment: Thank you. What counts as a 'remote' database?

Comment: anything that is not in your home.